# HowTo: Handle this situation?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, downvotes

I'm not sure if this has been asked already, but, I was recently faced with the following situation and would like to know the best way to handle it.  I provided an answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129730/creating-a-new-registry-folder-with-a-space-and-a-forward-slash-in-the-folder-na/33130091#33130091).  The poster replied thanks, but, my solution did not work for him.  Then, the poster edited the question to change its context.  I think he may have realized that I may have misunderstood his question based on the context and the way it was worded.  He added clarification.  Later, someone down-voted my answer (for some unknown reason).  Granted the down-vote is minimal, but, I'm not sure it was deserved based on the sequence of events.  Is this something we all need to accept, or, was there a different course of action I could have taken?

Comment: If the question started out clear, but then changed to something _significantly different_, you could rollback the edit.  Otherwise, it's really an appropriate edit, and you'll have to deal with it.  As for the downvote, it looks like a drive by to me.  Just bad luck.

Comment: [Run, run, run run away ...](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YjTWqOAAhAo)

Comment: The title of this question both delights and enrages me.